# Loop and Array - Show Strings

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, string, loops

I am trying to show a group variables that contains a string from the code behind (C#) to Textblock in XAML using the code below:

```
 Textblock1.Text = String1Class;
 Textblock2.Text = String2Class;
 Textblock3.Text = String3Class;
 Textblock4.Text = String4Class;
 Textblock5.Text = String5Class;
 Textblock6.Text = String6Class;
```

The code works but its a pain writing the same thing over and over again.
I want to ask if there is a better way. I know it has to do with arrays and loops, but I am not very familiar with C# and WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that you have separate variables for each of the `StringXClass` values you need to do this if you want to keep the variables the same:

```
var tbs = new [] { Textblock1, Textblock2, Textblock3, Textblock4, Textblock5, Textblock6, };
var scs = new [] { String1Class, String2Class, String3Class, String4Class, String5Class, String6Class, };

for (var i = 0; i < tbs.Length; i++)
{
    tbs.Text = scs;
}
```

The alternative is to set up an array in the first place.

```
var StringClass = new string[6];
```

Then replace `String1Class` with `StringClass[0]`, `String2Class` with `StringClass[1]`, etc, in your code.

Then write this:

```
var tbs = new [] { Textblock1, Textblock2, Textblock3, Textblock4, Textblock5, Textblock6, };
for (var i = 0; i < tbs.Length; i++)
{
    tbs.Text = StringClass[i];
}
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the TextBlocks if they are in the same parent:

```
string controlName = "TextBlock";
int startIndex = 1;
int endIndex = 100;

List<string>  stringList = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
    stringList.Add("string"+(i+1).ToString());

for(int i = startIndex; i<=endIndex; i++)
{
    foreach(control c in TextBlock1.Parent.Controls)//Or if you know the actual parent to which all the textBoxes belong
    {
        if(c.Name == (controlName+i))
        {               
            (c as TextBlock).Text = stringsList[i-1]; //since our start index starts with 1. 
            break;                   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**XAML:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="TextBlock1"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="TextBlock2"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="TextBlock3"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="TextBlock4"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

**Code:**

```
TextBlock[] textboxes = { TextBlock1, TextBlock2, TextBlock3, TextBlock4 };
string[] list = { "TextBlock 1", "TextBlock 2", "TextBlock 3", "TextBlock 4" };

for (int i = 0; i < textboxes.Length; i++)
{
    textboxes[i].Text = list[i];
}
```

**Output:**

[image]